# How to change actionbar menu item text color in Android 5.0

Tags: android

My action bare menu items have back text in Android 5.0. I am trying to change it to white but the style for android:actionMenuTextColor seems to be ignored and the text appears black

How can I change the menu item text color to white?

Here is my styles.xml i do not have a theme.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Red" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_red</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Red</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Red</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Red</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Red</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Red</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_red</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_red</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Red</item>

    <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Red.Widget</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/red_edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#99e84e40</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/red_text_select_handle_left</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/red_text_select_handle_right</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/red_text_select_handle_middle</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewred</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/red_btn_check_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/red_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Buttonred</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonred</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/Spinnerred</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBarred</item>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarred</item>
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyle">@style/RatingBarred</item>
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyleIndicator">@style/RatingBarBigred</item>
    <item name="android:ratingBarStyleSmall">@style/RatingBarSmallred</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Togglered</item>
    <item name="android:listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/red_list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/red_activated_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/red_fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="myCustomMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_red</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_red</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_red</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Red</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_red</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Red</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_red</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_red</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_red</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_red</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_red</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_red</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_red</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Red" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_red</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Red.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Red</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Red</item>
</style>

<style name="AutoCompleteTextViewred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/red_list_selector_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_edit_text_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Buttonred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_btn_default_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="ImageButtonred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_btn_default_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Spinnerred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/red_list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Tabred">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_tab_indicator_holo</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextred">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <!-- v14 <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item> -->
    <item name="android:ellipsize">marquee</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">180dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBarred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/red_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/red_progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="SeekBarred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/red_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/red_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/red_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="RatingBarred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_full_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_full_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="RatingBarBigred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Indicator">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="RatingBarSmallred" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.RatingBar.Small">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_small_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/red_ratingbar_small_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="Togglered" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_btn_toggle_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your values-v21:

`<item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@style/Theme.Red.Widget</item>`